# Prevent child triggers call in Firebase functions

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Good day, I have a little difficulty with the behavior of child triggers in the firebase functions. For demonstration I created a small project.

1. We have a realtime database strucrure like this: [image: start]
2. And firebse triggers.First trigger increases count when item create.Second decreases count when item deleted. Last trigger delete items when list deleted :

```js
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
admin.initializeApp();

// ON CREATE ITEM 
export const onItemCraate  = functions.database.ref('listItems/{listKey}/{itemKey}').onCreate(async(snapshot, context)=>{
  try{
      return  admin.database().ref(`list/${context.params.listKey}/itemCount`).transaction(count =>{
        return count+1;
    });
  }catch (error){
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(error.code, error.message, error.details);
  }
})

// ON DELETE ITEM 
export const onItemDelete  = functions.database.ref('listItems/{listKey}/{itemKey}').onDelete(async(snapshot, context)=>{
  try{
      return  admin.database().ref(`list/${context.params.listKey}/itemCount`).transaction(count =>{
        return count-1;
    });
  }catch (error){
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(error.code, error.message, error.details);
  }
},)

// ON LIST DELETE
export const onListDelete  = functions.database.ref('list/{listKey}').onDelete(async(snapshot, context)=>{
  try{
      return  admin.database().ref(`listItems/${context.params.listKey}`).remove();
  }catch (error){
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(error.code, error.message, error.details);
  }
})
```

So the problem is: when I delete list, and "onDeleteList" trigger delete item firebase cast "onItemDelete" trigger for each listItem. And after that update "itemCount" in "ghost" list.
Is there some way to prevent child triggers calls  when the parent is removed?  Pictures below:

before delete
[image: delete]

after delete
[image: after delete]

log
[image: log]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there some way to prevent child triggers calls when the parent is removed?

No. Child nodes are deleted implicitly when a parent node is deleted, and that will always trigger onDelete functions that would match the child node path.

If you want the trigger to do something different in certain circumstances, the function will have to be coded to detect that situation and act accordingly.